# tKinter canvas - .create_image() doesn't show on canvas

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, canvas

**Fix: Make the image global**

I have a secondary .py file that's generated from tKinterdesigner that creates and puts all images onto the canvas by using the ".create_image" method. I have my main file open this secondary gui-file, but the images does not show. Not the image for the button nor the background.

But if i force an error, some of the images are shown.

Image put inside label, but now it overlays the text.

In code:
I like to use #1. since this is transparent and my text should show, but then the image isn't showing.
When using #2 and #3, the image is shown, but the text is hidden behind i would think?

```
from tkinter import Button, Label, PhotoImage, Toplevel, Canvas
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def open_prosjektinfo():
    prosjektinfo = Toplevel()
    prosjektinfo.geometry("270x350")
    prosjektinfo.title("Prosjektinfo")
    prosjektinfo.resizable(False, False)

    canvas_prosjektinfo = Canvas(
    prosjektinfo,
    bg = "#CDCDCD",
    height = 350,
    width = 270,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
    )

    canvas_prosjektinfo.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    
    # 1.
    global background_prosjektinfo
    background_prosjektinfo = PhotoImage(
        file=("assets/prosjektinfo.png"))
    canvas_prosjektinfo.create_image(
        135.0,
        175.0,
        image=background_prosjektinfo
    )
    
    # 2.
    """global img
    path = r"assets/prosjektinfo.png"
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    panel = Label(prosjektinfo, image=img)
    panel.place(x=0, y=0)"""

    # 3.
    """background_prosjektinfo_label = Label(prosjektinfo, image=background_prosjektinfo)
    background_prosjektinfo_label.image = background_prosjektinfo # Keep a reference
    background_prosjektinfo_label.place(x=0, y=0)"""

    canvas_prosjektinfo.create_text(
        18.0,
        190.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="Beskrivelse:",
        fill="#000000",
        font=("Poppins Regular", 12 * -1)
    )

    def lagre_prosjektinfo():
        prosjektinfo.destroy()
    
    global button_lagreoglukk_image
    button_lagreoglukk_image = PhotoImage(
        file=("assets/lagreoglukk.png"))
    button_lagreoglukk = Button(
        prosjektinfo,
        image=button_lagreoglukk_image,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lagre_prosjektinfo,
        relief="flat"
    )
    button_lagreoglukk.place(
        x=70.0,
        y=273.0,
        width=131.0,
        height=38.0
    )
```

Comment: When you call `canvas_prosjektinfo.create_image`, `create_image` is connected to `canvas_prosjektinfo`. That is the only canvas it can possibly write to.

Comment: And is it not possible to do imagebuttons since the image must be put inside a label? And the text doesn't show, and creating label-text doesn't have transparent background?

Comment: Images can be drawn directly on a canvas. You do not have to use a label if you want the image on the canvas. Also, buttons can have images.

Comment: Even if the canvas is in a function on another .py? Mine just didn’t show when they were inside a function and not in a label

Comment: Yes, the code doesn't care what file a function or object is defined in. As long as you have a reference, it doesn't matter what created that reference.

Comment: You need to provide a _complete_ [mcve] in your question. Not a full program, it needs to be minimal but it also needs to be complete.

Comment: Added global to the image, and that fixed it.